# Azure Blob Storage Indexer fails on images

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-search

I'm using Azure Search with a Blob Storage indexer.  I'm seeing failures in the execution history:-

```
[
    {
        "key": null,
        "errorMessage": "Document 'https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/my-documents/Document/Repository/F/AD/LO/LO-min-0002-00.png' has unsupported content type 'image/png'"
    }
]
```

Does this failure cause other documents (with supported content type) in the storage not to be indexed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by default 1 failed document will stop indexing. You can increase that limit if you just have an occasional unsupported document. You can add `AzureSearch_Skip` metadata to the blobs you don't want to index as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage/).

**UPDATE** You can also skip all blobs with certain file extensions from indexing - see [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage/#using-indexer-parameters-to-control-document-extraction) for details. This allows you to easily skip all .jpeg or .png files, for example.

Also, please vote for this UserVoice suggestion: [Blob indexer should be able to skip unsupported content types instead of treating them as errors](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/11628435-blob-indexer-should-be-able-to-skip-unsupported-co)

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice work around.  How do you know what the supported content types are?

Comment: The list of supported content types is listed in [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage/). All others are unsupported. Please let us know on UserVoice which additional formats you'd like to see supported.